# I am trying to find a suitable promQL on Thanos Query which will give me the count of Readiness and Liveness Probe failures

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, grafana, promql, thanos

I am trying to migrate a dashboard which shows the count of Readiness and Liveness Probe Failures, from Kibana(ElasticSearch) to a Grafana Dashboard(Sauron). In kibana the we can get both the probe failures separately using `kubernetes.event.message : Liveness probe failed` for Liveness failure and similar event message for Readiness, but in Sauron or Thanos (which acts as the datasource for Grafana) k8's event messages are not picked up. So I am unable to find a suitable promQL which will give me the count of both the probe failures individually.

The closest promQL I have found is `kube_event_count{reason="Unhealthy"}` which is giving me the sum of the count of both the probe failures. I need the count of the probe failures individually. Another promQL that I have tried is `kube_pod_container_status_ready` which probably gives the readiness status of the containers but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

The following two queries will do the trick for you:

```
prober_probe_total{probe_type="Readiness",result="failed"}
```

```
prober_probe_total{probe_type="Liveness",result="failed"}
```

Comment: Sorry but this 'prober_probe_total' query is not available for me. Can you suggest any other probably from kubernetes state-metrics or event exporter metrics.

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you using? It seems strange to me that you don't have the indicated metrics... here the doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/instrumentation/metrics/#list-of-alpha-kubernetes-metrics

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/issues/699